# Is there a secure way to copy Userforms to another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I’m looking into doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479289/copy-userform-to-another-workbook) in Excel VBA to copy multiple userforms to another workbook. This works but requires us to enable `Trust Macro` Settings. Not sure if I want to do this on all PCs. Is there a way to copy userforms to another workbook programmatically without having to enable Trust Add-ins? Based on the choices, a different set of UserForms will need to be selected, so creating a template will be much harder to maintain.

Comment: Thankfully, there is no way code can be pasted into a computer without the user's agreement. Any backdoor to obtaining Trust clearance would defeat its purpose. However, the reason for your presumption that multiple user forms in a template would make it hard to maintain is a self-created hurdle. You could distribute all forms to all users and restrict access to them programmatically, perhaps based on the UserName, or a code that is entered as a document property. That would leave you with a single template which should be easier to maintain than what you have now.

Comment: I figured as much. My use case is different where  the .xlsm needs to be emailed to specific people with some people that they manage. Because these data are sensitive, the client doesn't want it to be shared, and they want the application to be using a macro. I know, it's bad. But still was trying to see if there's a way to do this somehow. Thanks for the clarification, @Variatus!

Comment: @Variatus, I didn't mean "multiple user forms are hard to maintain". I meant to say that having multiple files and templates for different use case is hard to maintain. My use case is as follows: Group A filters data according to memberID in B and sends to each member in group B. B filters the data according to memberID in C and sends to each member in C. C then interacts with the form and stores the data in the sheet and send it to B. B collects all sheets and sends to A. A maintains the final data. It's a bad design, but client wants it this way.

Comment: Clear. What I meant is that you might give everybody the same code but let them use different parts of it. So, say, form C is included in your standard template even though only group C uses it. Your problem would shift from how to make a form available to the one who needs it to how to block a user who isn't supposed to access it. To solve that problem you don't need trusted access. Therefore the suggestion would resolve your current dilemma.

Comment: @Variatus, Got it! That’s helpful. Thanks